# Google Maps: InfoWindow with Chart from fusion table and depending on selected layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I would like to visualise a number of variables per country on a world map. With Google Fusion Tables I set up the map. Now I would like to flip between the variables/layers (Var_A and Var_B) I would like to visualise with a dropdown menu. I followed the code the Guardian used in [this article](http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/interactive/2012/sep/13/hate-crime-map-england-wales).
In this example the formatting of the info window in the FusionTable itself seems to simply show up but that doesn't work for me.

This is the fusion table: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&t=TABLE&q=select+col0%2C+col1%2C+col2%2C+col3%2C+col4%2C+col5%2C+col6%2C+col7+from+19I14XgRDOk7697iWA8XSukbYBBelNRymFOqjw_ru&containerId=googft-gviz-canvas

Clicking on the respective country I would like to display an info window, which shows a chart (bar chart for example) showing the values Var_A and Var_A1 when Layer 'Var_A' is selected and Var_B and Var_B1 when Layer 'Var_B' is selected.

I tried with the code example in [Add a google chart to a infowindow using google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668202/add-a-google-chart-to-a-infowindow-using-google-maps-api) ....

```
   function drawChart(marker) {

        var node        = document.createElement('div'),
            infoWindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
            chart       = new google.visualization.PieChart(node);

            chart.draw(data, options);
            infoWindow.setContent(node);
            infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(),marker);
      }
```

... but not even the static google chart worked for me.

So I really have three problems here:

1) show ANY chart in the info window

2) show a chart using data from the respective data row (country)

3) show a chart using data from the respective data row (country) and depending on the selected layer

I tried for a couple of days now with many unsuccessful ways and I am stuck - ready to leave google maps if I can not get it to work. This is the fiddle of the last thing that did at least show a map - I had to remove all event listeners again...

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sytpp/ovfauhwb/

Any help greatly apprechiated!!

Answer (score 0):

observe the click-event of the FusionTablesLayer, you will get there the values for the particular row:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer,'click',function(e){
    //which values need to be drawn in the chart, A or B ?
    var prefix=document.getElementById('selector').value,

    //collect the data
    row={title:e.row.Country.value,rows:[]};
    //Var_A or Var_B
    row.rows.push([prefix,Number(e.row[prefix].value)]);
    //Var_A or Var_B1
    row.rows.push([prefix+'1',Number(e.row[prefix+'1'].value)]);
    //call drawChart by passing the collected data and clicked position as arguments 
    drawChart(row,e.latLng);
});
```

Now use the data(Note: you may initially set the content of the infoWindow to an empty div-element, there is no need to create a new node each time)

```
function drawChart(row,position) {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //set the scheme
    data.addColumn('string', 'label');
    data.addColumn('number', 'amount');
    //add the data
    data.addRows(row.rows);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':row.title,
                   'width':300,
                   'height':200,
                   legend:'none'};

    //assuming the infoWindow already has the content set to a DOMNode, e.g. a div
    var chart       = new google.visualization.BarChart(infoWindow.getContent());

    chart.draw(data, options);

    infoWindow.setOptions({map:map,position:position});

}
```

**Note:** you must set the `suppressInfoWindows`-option of the FusionTablesLayer to `true`, otherwise 2 InfoWindows will open, the built-in and the custom where the chart will be drawn.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/o1fyarnf/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/o1fyarnf/)